# Is there a non-blocking version of MessageBox.Show (or something like it)?

Tags: .net, winforms, blocking, messagebox, nonblocking

### Long-delayed update

I'm accepting MUG4N's answer to this question, and I also want to respond to some of the criticisms that were raised against it.

ChrisF said:

> ...you can't make UI calls directly from background threads.

This is a blanket statement, and is not 100% true. Let me just point out a few facts:

1. You can actually make UI calls *all you want* if you set `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false`. *"Ack!"* I hear you saying. *"Don't **ever** do that!"* Yes, yes -- but **why**? The answer: because **sometimes** this will corrupt memory.

   The control classes in `System.Windows.Forms` are not written to be thread-safe, so sometimes updating them from background threads can corrupt memory. But if this only *sometimes* happens and not *always*, what this tells me is that **it is not the calling of UI code *per se*, but rather the potentially unsafe *collision* of UI code that can cause exceptions**.
2. To reinforce point 1, consider this: the "safe" way to invoke UI code from a background thread is to do so using `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, right? **But this *is* a UI call**; it's just *the* UI call we're supposed to make if we're updating the GUI from a non-GUI thread. What I mean is, clearly, it is not simply invoking "any" method on a `Control` object from an outside thread that's going to cause chaos (if that were the case, then we couldn't even call `Invoke` and we'd be stuck completely). Again, it's the potential collision of separate UI calls that cannot safely occur simultaneously that will prove destructive.
3. Keeping the above two points in mind, ask yourself: why would it be unsafe to call `MessageBox.Show` from a non-GUI thread? A completely separate `Form` is created and displayed; its properties do not in any way interact with any other existing GUI object; in fact, it cannot be accessed *anywhere* in *any manner*, except for one: from the calling thread, which accesses its `DialogResult` property (and only that via the `Show` method's return value).

Moving along. Conrad Albrecht said:

> ...given the assertion that Show() sets up its own message pump in Dan's ref'd topic, (which was not substantiated, but which I can't refute)...

This is a totally fair point (though I personally hold Jared Par in high enough esteem that I wouldn't generally be inclined to *doubt* what he says). In any case, a peek at the `MessageBox.Show` method through [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) reveals this snippet:

```
Application.BeginModalMessageLoop();
try
{
    result = Win32ToDialogResult(SafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(new HandleRef(owner, zero), text, caption, type));
}
finally
{
    Application.EndModalMessageLoop();
    UnsafeNativeMethods.ThemingScope.Deactivate(userCookie);
}
```

A further peek into the `Application.BeginModalMessageLoop` method reveals this:

```
ThreadContext.FromCurrent().BeginModalMessageLoop(null);
```

And this `ThreadContext.FromCurrent`, in turn:

```
// [Reflector shows that currentThreadContext is a ThreadStatic member. -Dan]
if (currentThreadContext == null)
{
    currentThreadContext = new Application.ThreadContext();
}
return currentThreadContext;
```

I don't know enough about these lower-level Windows constructs to fully understand this code, but this seems to me to be evidence of exactly what Jared was saying in the answer I referenced in my old comment (for curious readers: [Does MessageBox.Show() automatically marshall to the UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559252/does-messagebox-show-automatically-marshall-to-the-ui-thread)).

So, yeah. I am totally in agreement with MUG4N on this one.

(If anyone can convincingly argue that I am still mistaken here, please speak up. Although I feel I've made a pretty good case for why I believe MUG4N is right, I'm obviously not 100% certain.)

---

### Original question

Often you just want to notify the user that something has occurred, but there's really no need for any input from them. In this common scenario, I sometimes see code like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Something has occurred", "Something", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

This code, as we all know, causes a little pop-up window to appear with only an **OK** button. Now here's the thing: this code blocks (the UI thread). But in the vast majority of cases, it seems to me, if you *only* have an **OK** button, there's very little need to block. (Isn't the purpose of blocking typically to receive some input from the user? And if the user's *only* choice is "OK," in this typical case, isn't blocking pretty pointless?)

Obviously I could just write my own little form that does basically exactly what `MessageBox.Show` does, except that it returns nothing (no `DialogResult`) and doesn't block. But I was just wondering if something like this exists already that I didn't know about.

Comment: The intention of a message box is to get the user either to decide on (if you have cancel etc.) or acknowledge something (if it is just OK) before he/she can continue. - I think you should reconsider your UI design if you think you require non-modal message boxes. What is the use case?

Comment: @Patrick: The use case is notifying the user that something has occurred. Suppose the user activates some process within the application and then walks away from the computer to go to the bathroom. When they come back, they want to know if the process has finished. To me, a message box is the most logical way to signal this to the user. At the same time, it may be desirable that this message box will not have prevented the application from continuing to run additional processes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use multi threading to perform this task in which one thread (the main thread) will do the processing and the other thread will be used to show the messagebox.

Comment: @MUG4N: That's one approach. But `MessageBox.Show` will still block the thread from which it's called, right? I guess what you're saying is I could just write a new method that calls `MessageBox.Show` from a background thread, is that right?

Comment: @Dan - you can't make UI calls directly from background threads.

Comment: @ChrisF: In my experience, you **can** call `MessageBox.Show` from a background thread. I realize this probably isn't encouraged, but I haven't found any documentation indicating that it should absolutely not be done. I actually upvoted this answer after testing it out myself. It worked -- *without* setting `Control. CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to `true`.

Comment: @Conrad: Seriously? Did you *try* what MUG4N suggested? It works perfectly. Furthermore, according to my research, it seems that calling `MessageBox.Show` from a background thread is actually *perfectly fine*. See, for instance, Jared Par's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559252/does-messagebox-show-automatically-marshall-to-the-ui-thread

Comment: "It works" when you happen to test it is no vindication for threading bugs, which fail unpredictably. But, given the assertion that Show() sets up its own message pump in Dan's ref'd topic, (which was not substantiated, but which I can't refute) I'll retract my downvote. [or I would retract if StacO would let me]

Comment: As an example, this is working well for me:
`new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show("message")).Start();`

Answer (score 7):

What about adding a [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) to your application and displaying a [balloon tip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx)? The down side is that the notification will disappear after a short time, but maybe that's best for your users if they don't need to take action.

There are more suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198868/suggestions-for-a-messagebox-show-replacement-that-does-not-block-gui-thread).

Comment: +1 In my mind, this is really more a question of UI metaphors than it is about the threading behaviors of particular widge classes. If you're looking for non-modal behavior with an alert, something other than a MessageBox seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

What I would try is call the [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) function from the Win32 API directly, like :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int MessageBox(int h, string m, string c, int type);
```

Try using a null handle, and the APPLMODAL type. That may work.

Comment: This is as blocking as it gets.  "The message box returns an integer value that indicates which button the user clicked."  Clearly it can't do this if it returns before the dialog is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but nevertheles...

1) Import IWshShell ('Windows Script Host Object Model')

Dim wsh As New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
        wsh.Popup(String.Concat(Me.GetType.FullName, vbCrLf, _
                                        Application.ExecutablePath), 0.75, "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel Or MessageBoxIcon.Question)

Jens...