# Where can I find some information on "MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox"?

Tags: winapi, win32gui

In C# application, I want know how work `MessageBox`. But I block on this method:

```
MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(HandleRef hWnd, String text, String caption, Int32 type)
```

My question is the same in suject title:

> Where can I find some information on this method?

Comment: [You're not interested in some or even all information](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/02/10263027.aspx). Please explain what you are trying to do and what problem your current approach introduces and how you would like to solve that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a non-blocking version of MessageBox.Show (or something like it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834101/is-there-a-non-blocking-version-of-messagebox-show-or-something-like-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox` is just a reference to the native API function [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It blocks because that is what it does: it is waiting for you to press a button.

Comment: It is not application block, but my undertanding. I search some think like MSDN who explain what this method make. This link like well. Thank.